# XSL if ContentType has a given value

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I am trying to determine content type of the item. I tried this but I think ContentType in results.aspx webpart is known with another name.

```
<xsl:if contenttype="mycustomcontenttype"> 
 <xsl:Value-of select="contenttype" />
<xsl:if>
```

Comment: May I know the reason for negative mark? So I can better understand how to post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT is badly formatted.

There is no such `xsl:if` attribute called `contenttype` - nor is there an `<xsl:Value-of` because all instructions are case-sensitive, and should be in lower case.

Your code should be something like this...

```
<xsl:if test="contenttype='mycustomcontenttype'"> 
 <xsl:value-of select="contenttype" />
<xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thank you for claring it up for me. Appreciated it.

Comment: Not a problem @user - good luck with your project :-)  I wasn't the downvoter (which appears to have been removed now), but you should always try and give as much information in your questions... fortunately it was fairly easy to see what the issue was in this case

Answer (score 1):

**Or even this one-liner** (no conditionals used at all):

```
<xsl:value-of select="contenttype[.='mycustomcontenttype']"/>
```